# iOS 9: Determine size of collection view in portrait and landscape

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, height, ios9, statusbar

I have a simple UICollectionViewController with FlowLayout embedded in an UINavigationController.

In the UICollectionViewFlowDelegate I try to calculate the size of a cell depending on the actual available size of the collection view on the screen.

The standard behavior on iOS 9 seems to be that in portrait the status bar is 20px high and visible and the navigation bar is 44px high and visible. In landscape the status bar is hidden and the navigation bar is 32px in height.

The problem is that when I try to calculate my cell size based on these figures, I get wrong data in the collectionView:sizeForItemAtIndexPath function.

I put the following code in this function to demonstrate the values I get

```
    print ("Device......: " + UIDevice.currentDevice().name)
    print ("Model.......: " + UIDevice.currentDevice().localizedModel)
    print ("Orientation.: " + String(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.rawValue))
    print ("View width..: " + String(self.view.bounds.size.width))
    print ("View height.: " + String(self.view.bounds.size.height))
    print ("S.bar height: " + String(UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.height))
    print ("S.bar hidden: " + String(UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden))
    print ("N.bar height: " + String(self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height))
```

When the app starts in portrait on an iPhone 6 simulator, I get the following output:

```
Device......: iPhone Simulator
Model.......: iPhone
Orientation.: 1
View width..: 375.0
View height.: 603.0
S.bar height: 20.0
S.bar hidden: false
N.bar height: Optional(44.0)
```

So far so good as this is expected. When I then rotate the device to landscape, I get this:

```
Device......: iPhone Simulator
Model.......: iPhone
Orientation.: 4
View width..: 667.0
View height.: 323.0
S.bar height: 20.0
S.bar hidden: false
N.bar height: Optional(32.0)
```

Now the view height is 20px off the actual view height and the height of the status bar is shown as 20 while it is actually 0. Also the status bar is indicated as visible while it is actually hidden. But it gets even stranger.

When I rotate the device back to portrait I then get this:

```
Device......: iPhone Simulator
Model.......: iPhone
Orientation.: 1
View width..: 375.0
View height.: 623.0
S.bar height: 0.0
S.bar hidden: true
N.bar height: Optional(44.0)
```

So it seems that the calculation of the height of the status bar is somewhere delayed.

The question now is how I can calculate the size of the visible part of a collection view within the function

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
```

Note on the side:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden
```

is deprecated in iOS 9.

**Edit #1:**

On the iPhone 6 Plus and 6s Plus simulator I seem to get the expected values. 4s, 5, 6 and 6s give the values shown in the question.

Comment: You need to use :

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { 
    println("height :\(view.bounds.size.height)")
    println("width :\(view.frame.size.width)")

   // all other code depends on UIDevice.current.orientation
This code will be executed after the rotation was completed (in the main queue) and the new sizes are available.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just directly access the UICollectionView frame property?

In the this method

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
```

Just access `colllectionView.frame` and calculate size based on it.

You should never rely on hard coded values for heights as these things can change in the new release of iOS.

Comment: Does not work as `collectionView.frame.height` returns the same (wrong) value as `self.view.bounds.size.height` . Also the whole point of the question is to avoid hardcoded values. This is why I try to calculate the size in the first place.

Comment: Are you reloading your data after the layout has completed?

Comment: No, I did not. Reloading in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` did the trick. Thanks!. One note on the side: If I do not also reload the data in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` (which I did), then there are very ugly interim visual transition effects.

Comment: I do appreciate your help! Thanks again for this. I will nevertheless leave this question as unsolved for now as the OS actually requests a new cell size on rotation. It's just not possible to calculate it correctly as the value for the status bar is off. The reloading of the data just triggers a second recalculation and should to my current understanding not be necessary.

Comment: If you do not want to reload UICollectionView you can just call `invalidateLayout`. It will only reload the layout and not the model.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) 
   { 
      println("height :(view.bounds.size.height)") 
      println("width :(view.frame.size.width)") 
     // all other code depends on UIDevice.current.orientation 
    }
```

This code will be executed after the rotation was completed (in the main queue) and the new sizes are available.